# How to turn each value in a list into a list of lists, made of values from a function

Tags: r, list

I have a list of >1000 values. dput(head(list)):

```
list("WP100", "WP106", "WP107", "WP111", "WP117", "WP12")
```

Function getXrefList from rWikiPathways package produces a new list of associated genes for each WP value.

input: (H parameter gives genes in the external gene format)

```
library(rWikiPathways)
getXrefList(list[[1]], 'H')
```

output:

```
 [1] "ANPEP" "G6PD"  "GCLC"  "GCLM"  "GGT1"  "GGT5"  "GPX1"  "GPX2"  "GPX3"  "GPX4"  "GSR"   "GSS"   "GSTA1"
[14] "GSTA5" "GSTM1" "GSTM2" "GSTT2" "IDH1"  "OPLAH"
```

I would like to turn the original list into a list of lists. The WP value being the ith values and the jth values being the resulting list of genes from getXrefList function.

---

Current progress:

```
new_list <- lapply(list, function(x){getXrefList(x, 'H')})
new_list[[1]]
```

output:

```
 "ANPEP" "G6PD"  "GCLC"  "GCLM"  "GGT1"  "GGT5"  "GPX1"  "GPX2" "GPX3"  "GPX4"  "GSR"   "GSS"   "GSTA1" "GSTA5" "GSTM1" "GSTM2" "GSTT2" "IDH1"  "OPLAH"
```

---

Wheras the ideal output would look something like this:

```
List
    WP100
          "ANPEP" "G6PD"  "GCLC"  "GCLM"  "GGT1"  "GGT5"  "GPX1"  "GPX2" "GPX3"  "GPX4"  "GSR"   "GSS"   "GSTA1" "GSTA5" "GSTM1" "GSTM2" "GSTT2" "IDH1"  "OPLAH"
    WP106 
          "ABAT" "AGXT" "ASL"  "ASPA" "ASS1" "DARS" "GAD1" "GAD2" "GOT1" "GOT2" "GPT"  "PC"
```

And so forth in this fashion. Any help would be appreciated.

Solved. Easy fix.

```
names(new_list) <- list
```

Comment: you are using `x[[1]]` in the `lapply` call? Try `lapply(list, function(x) getXrefList(x, 'H'))`

Comment: @RonakShah this worked better than my lapply function. However the output does not keep the WP elements as the ith value. Is there a way to keep the WP elements as the list names/ith values ?

Comment: do `new_list <- lapply(list, function(x) getXrefList(x, 'H'))` and then access it as `new_list[[1]]`, `new_list[[2]]` and so on.

Comment: I have updated the question.